# PGC map but no entry

Tags: android, dalvik, android-logcat, pgcc

Got this the other day and have no idea what it means in my android logs for a program I was debugging:

```
dalvikvm:    PGC: map but no entry for Lcom/myapp/Uploader;.run addr=0x01ab
```

Should I be worried?

Comment: Apparently I shouldn't be worried as no one else seems to have seem this error.

Answer (score 2):

Looking briefly at Git code, it seems to be during garbadge collection: A Map is found with no entry in it, everything seems ok. For what I saw, it's just the debug log seems to have been forgoten her, even thought I'm not sure of it.